# object detection wood piles in image opencv c++

Tags: object, detection

I want to search wood piles in image. Secondly wantbto remove other areas aground the wood piles e.g grass , sky and trees.
I have used sobel on grayscale, h and v I can see the wood piles in circle but failed to remove otherness grass etc.

Comment: Too broad question. What have you tried so far? Read carefully the http://stackoverflow.com/tour